# Why Does My Heil Furnace Start When It Should Be Off?

Tags: hvac, furnace, thermostat

My Heil furnace starts with the thermostat set to off. I disconnected the thermostat wires at the thermostat and it still starts randomly.  I disconnected the heating wire at the board and it still does it.  So I guess it is not a short.

The board does not throw any code that can be read after it starts then stops.  It does flash 4 in the middle of a random start which is main limit or rollout 'open'.

It does not light or try to light; both fans just turn on.  It may stay on for 5 minutes or 5 seconds and it is very random.  (Though 15-20 seconds is typical.) It might cycle on/off 10 time in 5 min or just one every couple of hours for 20 seconds.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it just the blower that runs, or do the burners light?

Comment: If it's just the blower, it could be that the high limit is on the way out.  If the high limit is opening, the blower would come on to remove the "excess heat".